# $\gcd(a,b)$ is nonconstant and $b$ irreducible, then $b = \pm pp(a)$?

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to prove the following result.

Let $a$, $b$ be polynomials with integer coefficients ($a$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}[x])$.

If:

- $a \neq 0$
- $\gcd(a,b)$  is nonconstant
- degree $a \le$ degree $b$
- $b$ is irreducible

Then  $b = \pm pp(a)$, where $pp(a)$ denotes the primitive part of $a$.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If a polynomial is irreducible and shares a nonconstant gcd with another polynomial, it can mean only one thing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial $b$ is irreducible and hence primitive.
List all divisors of $b$. One of them will be $gcd(a,b)$ (which one?).
Now, $gcd(a,b)$ also divides $a$. Compare the degrees to get the desired result.